# Calculated Column with Multiple Queries

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

This may seem really basic but I'm struggling to get my head around it. I have 2 boolean columns (Checked by TL and Checked by CSS), I need a calculated column to give me one of three results;

1: Checked by Both - this is where both of the columns are True

2: Checked by CSS - this is where the Checked by CSS column is True and the Checked by TL column is False

3: Checked by TL - this is where the Checked by TL column is True and the Checked by CSS column is False

I may have used the right formula in my testing but kept getting a syntax error which I couldn't fix by bracket counting so I'd appreciate any help with this one

Solved;

```
=IF(AND([Checked by CSS]=TRUE,[Checked by TL]=TRUE),"Checked by Both",IF(AND([Checked by CSS]=FALSE,[Checked by TL]=TRUE),"Checked by TL",IF(AND([Checked by CSS]=FALSE,[Checked by TL]=FALSE),"Unchecked",IF(AND([Checked by CSS]=TRUE,[Checked by TL]=FALSE),"Checked by CSS"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below formula:

```
=IF(AND([Checked by CSS]=TRUE,[Checked by TL]=TRUE),"Checked by Both",IF(AND([Checked by CSS]=TRUE,[Checked by TL]=FALSE),"Checked by CSS",IF(AND([Checked by CSS]=FALSE,[Checked by TL]=FALSE),"Unchecked",IF(AND([Checked by CSS]=FALSE,[Checked by TL]=TRUE),"Checked by TL"))))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Return your calculated field as **Single line of text**.

**official documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).